# Blooming with ros industrial CI pipelines

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have a private repo on bitbucket cloud that I've integrated with Industrial_CI, which so far just does catkin build test on a docker image for me.This provides the CI framework for me, but I'd like to bloom and release my binaries. Is there a way to automate this?

I'm on bitbucket cloud so I've been using their pipelines to do this. Would ros build farm be a better solution for CI+ release?

Is ros buildfarm the only buildfarm solution outside of custom build farms? Is there something that works tightly with industrial_ci that i'm not aware of?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355287/blooming-with-ros-industrial-ci-pipelines/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-19**:
Did you also post [ros-industrial/industrial_ci#535](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_ci/issues/535)?

**Comment by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on 2020-06-19**:
@gvdhoorn yes I did

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-20**:
Then please close either the issue on the Github tracker or your question here.

Cross-posting like that is not a nice thing to do. It leads to split discussions in the best case, and duplicated (ie: wasted) effort in the worst.

Give the maintainer some time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there something that works tightly with industrial_ci that i'm not aware of?

`industrial_ci` does not create binaries that can/should be released and there are no plans to extend it into this direction.

> but I'd like to bloom and release my binaries. Is there a way to automate this?

I would strongly advise against automating the release to the **public** ROS distros.
Releases need some oversight, especially during their preparation (version bumps, changelogs).

Running `bloom` is the easiest step. You can even write a bash one-liner to release your packages for multipe distros.

Of course, you can do this as well in the `deploy` stage of your CI system.

> Is ros buildfarm the only buildfarm solution outside of custom build farms?

[ros_buildfarm](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm) is the script system that is used in the official ROS buildfarm.

It can be used for custom buildfarms as well, but it requires some maintenance effort.
Another option is [buildbot-ros](https://github.com/mikeferguson/buildbot-ros).

Depending on your use case you might not even need a full-fledged buildfarm.
You could bundle your release in any way you like.

Several approaches have been presented during ROScons.

- https://roscon.ros.org/2016/ - Robust Deployment with ROS Bundles (Mike Purvis, Clearpath Robotics)
- https://roscon.ros.org/2018/ - Hermetic Robot Deployment Using Multi-Stage Dockers (Levon Avagyan, Fetch Robotics)
- https://roscon.ros.org/2019/ - Tailor CI: How Locus deploys ROS robots at scale (Paul Bovbel, Gary Servin, Locus Robotics)

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2020-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1